# Xpages - Accessing Display Error Control via JSF in SSJS

Tags: jsp, xpages-ssjs

I found a great little [Xsnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls) on the web to do validation in a SSJS script library.

It works well but there is one thing I want to change and I just can't. I want to put a Display Error Control to the right of the field that is being validated and have the error message appear there. Currently it appears in the header of the form in the lotusFormRequired and the lotusFormError section of the page.

In the picture below I don't want the error to be in the two Xed out areas and I do want it where the red box is.

Here is the code from the SSJS

```
var validateForm = function(){
  var valid = true;
  var control;
  var val;

  //Location Number is Required
  control = getComponent("LocNum");
  val = control.getValue();
  if (isEmpty(val)){
    valid = false;
    postValidationError(control,"Location Number Is Required");
  }   
  return valid;
}
function postValidationError(control, msg) {
    if ((typeof msg) != "string")
            return;
    var msgObj = new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
    facesContext.addMessage(control.getClientId(facesContext), msgObj);
    control.setValid(false);
}

function isEmpty(o){
  return (o == null || @Trim($A(o)[0]) == "" ) ? true : false;
}

function $A( object ){
  try {
    if( typeof object === 'undefined' || object === null ){ return []; }
    if( typeof object === 'string' ){ return [ object ]; }
    if( typeof object.toArray !== 'undefined' ){return object.toArray();}
    if( object.constructor === Array ){ return object; }  
    return [ object ];
  } catch( e ) { Debug.exceptionToPage( e ); }
}
```

[image]

Here is the code from the form row:

```
<xe:formRow labelPosition="none" id="frLocationNumber">
            <xp:table style="width:99%" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                role="presentation" cellspacing="0" id="tblLocation">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:10%;min-width:10%;">
                        <xp:label id="lblDocumentType"
                            value="Location Number" for="fieldDocType"
                            style="white-space:nowrap;">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputText id="LocNum"
                            value="#{document1.LocNum}" style="width:300.00px"
                            disableClientSideValidation="true">

                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:customValidator
                                validate="#{javascript:return false;}">
                                <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Incorrect"}]]></xp:this.message>
                            </xp:customValidator>
                        </xp:this.validators></xp:inputText>
                        <xp:message id="LocNumErrMsg" for="LocNum">
                        </xp:message></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xe:formRow>
```

Here is the CSS I added to the page to suppress the errors that I don't want.

```
/* This will suppress errors at the top of forms */

.lotusFormErrorSummary {
display: none;
} 
.lotusFormError {
display: none;
}
```

OK I spoke a little too soon. Works in the browser, but no in the client.

I found the definitive answer.

There is a property in the form table to disableErrorSummary. I set that to "True" and I am getting the behavior I want.

[image]

Comment: So find where the div id is and change it the right one.

Comment: Bryan, you need to move the Display Error control to the right of your fields. Show us your XPage for the New Location table

Comment: Per, I do have the Display Error control on the right of the field. I noticed that I did not have it set to visible, so it was not rendered. Now it renders, but I get the errors in the other two areas as well. I am not putting those there, I *believe* the code in the SSJS is and I don't want it to. Thanks.

Comment: OK I discovered that I can suppress two CSS classes and this will accomplish what I want. [See edited post]. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: OK I spoke a little too soon. Works in the browser, but no in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I found the definitive answer.

There is a property in the form table to disableErrorSummary. I set that to "True" and I am getting the behavior I want.

[image]